# My wireless does not work on rtl8723ae

Tags: wireless, networking

I have Ubuntu 14.04. The first time wireless worked great, but after I updated Ubuntu wireless did not work

OS Release

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

Kernel

```
Linux dead-Satellite-C850-B559 3.13.0-24-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 10 19:11:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`lspci`

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723AE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8723]
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:0723]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723ae
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device [1179:fb37]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
```

`lsusb`

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b307 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 04e8:61b3 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0930:021d Toshiba Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

#### PCMCIA Card Info

`rfkill`

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

`lsmod`

```
rtl8723ae              86464  0 
rtl_pci                26690  1 rtl8723ae
rtlwifi                63475  2 rtl_pci,rtl8723ae
mac80211              626489  3 rtl_pci,rtlwifi,rtl8723ae
cfg80211              484040  2 mac80211,rtlwifi
```

`iw reg get`

```
country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (3, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
```

`interfaces`

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto dsl-provider
iface dsl-provider inet ppp
pre-up /sbin/ifconfig wlan0 up # line maintained by pppoeconf
provider dsl-provider

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
```

`iwconfig`

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```

`route`

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
```

Content of `resolv.conf`

```
nameserver 127.0.1.1
search WAG54GS
```

`nm-tool`

```
NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: eth0  [Auto Ethernet] ------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8169
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        <MAC address removed>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           100 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         on

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.1.110
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.1.1

    DNS:             168.187.147.244

- Device: wlan0 ----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            rtl8723ae
  State:             unmanaged
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        <MAC address removed>

  Capabilities:

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points
```

`NetworkManager.state`

```
[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true
```

`NetworkManager.conf`

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

no-auto-default=<MAC address removed>,

[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

`iwlist`

```
wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC address removed>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=34/70  Signal level=-76 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Mayang511"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000007ceb466
                    Extra: Last beacon: 4ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 00094D6179616E67353131
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B962430486C
                    IE: Unknown: 030101
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                    IE: Unknown: 2F0100
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: 32040C121860
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1ABC011BFFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D1601080000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: DD090010180203000C0000
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F202010185000132000027A4000041435E0061322F00
          Cell 02 - Address: <MAC address removed>
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=32/70  Signal level=-78 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"nile"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000000c43d1942
                    Extra: Last beacon: 4ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 00046E696C65
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B962430486C
                    IE: Unknown: 030106
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                    IE: Unknown: 2F0100
                    IE: Unknown: 32040C121860
                    IE: Unknown: DD06001018020201
```

`iwlist channel`

```
wlan0     13 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
```

`modinfo`

```
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8723ae/rtl8723ae.ko
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8723fw_B.bin
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8723fw.bin
description:    Realtek 8723E 802.11n PCI wireless
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.Finger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     D3E2984FD11B8B20FAF9D09
alias:          pci:v000010ECd00008723sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        rtlwifi,rtl_pci,mac80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-24-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        <MAC address removed>:D9:06:21:70:6E:8D:06:60:4D:73:0B:35:9F:C0
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           swenc:Set to 1 for software crypto (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           ips:Set to 0 to not use link power save (default 1)
 (bool)
parm:           swlps:Set to 1 to use SW control power save (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           fwlps:Set to 1 to use FW control power save (default 1)
 (bool)
parm:           debug:Set debug level (0-5) (default 0) (int)

filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl_pci.ko
description:    PCI basic driver for rtlwifi
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.FInger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     B6B8AA929B5F982954A6DE1
depends:        mac80211,rtlwifi
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-24-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        <MAC address removed>:D9:06:21:70:6E:8D:06:60:4D:73:0B:35:9F:C0
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtlwifi.ko
description:    Realtek 802.11n PCI wireless core
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.FInger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     C21FC2F90947540319DE390
depends:        mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-24-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        <MAC address removed>:D9:06:21:70:6E:8D:06:60:4D:73:0B:35:9F:C0
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
```

**modules**

```
lp
rtc
```

**blacklist**

```
[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/fbdev-blacklist.conf]
blacklist arkfb
blacklist aty128fb
blacklist atyfb
blacklist radeonfb
blacklist cirrusfb
blacklist cyber2000fb
blacklist gx1fb
blacklist gxfb
blacklist kyrofb
blacklist matroxfb_base
blacklist mb862xxfb
blacklist neofb
blacklist nvidiafb
blacklist pm2fb
blacklist pm3fb
blacklist s3fb
blacklist savagefb
blacklist sisfb
blacklist tdfxfb
blacklist tridentfb
blacklist viafb
blacklist vt8623fb
```

**udev rules**

```
# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8136 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address removed>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"

# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8723 (rtl8723ae)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address removed>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"
```

`dmesg`

```
[   13.153939] rtl8723ae: Using firmware rtlwifi/rtl8723fw_B.bin
[   13.299994] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'rtl_rc'
[   13.300225] rtlwifi: wireless switch is on
[   14.520994] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
```

I have tried all the solutions I've seen. I have downloaded a lot of drivers but when I run the `make` command I get an error

[image: terminal screenshot with errors from make]

Comment: I'd strongly recommend using http://pastebin.com to make the outputs more readable.

Comment: ...or [formatting](http://askubuntu.com/help/formatting). How are you connecting the wireless adaptor? Could you please add a link to the outputs of `lsusb -t` & `lspci -v` (those outputs include the current drivers), and post a link to paste(s) on http://paste.ubuntu.com or pastebin.com.

Answer (score 0):

As a more general answer to your question, I've experienced much better performance with this network card following the advice from this user:

https://zach-adams.com/2014/06/fixing-rtl8723ae-driver-ubuntu-linux/

In short, two stages:

1. Try installing the linux-firmware-nonfree drivers with this command:

   `sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree`
2. Try installing the WICD network manager. For instructions for your version of Ubuntu, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WICD